# Angular 4 Animation with FormGroup with sections not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I have created an Angular animation for my FormGroup, so that different Form sections appear sequentially with animations. Here is the code-

```
animations:[ 
 trigger('visibilityChanged', [
    state('shown' , style({ opacity: 1 })),
    state('hidden', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    transition('shown => hidden', animate('600ms')),
    transition('void => *', animate('1000ms')),
    ])
 ]
```

And here is the html-

```
<form [formGroup]="regForm">
    <div *ngIf="showcontrol[0]" @visibilityChanged>
        <span id="formheading" class="text-center">ENTER TEAM DETAILS</span>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="teamname">Team Name:</label>
            <label class="validations" @load *ngIf="!regForm.get('team_name').valid && regForm.get('team_name').touched">Please Enter a Valid Team Name!</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="team_name" id="teamname" required placeholder="Enter Your Team Name">
        </div>
        .......
        ..
    </div>
```

Comment: I have a FormGroup with divisions like above with ngIf, There is a button which sets showcontrol[i+1] as true (and showcontrol[i] as false, so that next form group becomes visible and latter one hides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an animation on the group with *ngIf hidding/showing the group. In this solution I set only two values for the condition, but adapt it to your need. Also I set some styles which maybe need to be adapted to your need, too. But remember ngIf will remove the group if it's set to false, so the groups will 'move' if not styled:

**HTML:**

```
<form #individual="ngForm">
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div [@visibilityChanged] *ngIf="myCondition===1" class="myGroup1  form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text"  #myModel="ngModel"  class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" required placeholder="Enter Your Name">
      <label style="color:red" *ngIf="myModel.invalid">INVALID</label>
    </div>

    <div [@visibilityChanged] *ngIf="myCondition===2" class="myGroup2 form-group">
      <label for="name">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text"  #myModel="ngModel"  class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" required placeholder="Enter Your Name">
      <label style="color:red" *ngIf="myModel.invalid">INVALID</label>
    </div>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" (click)="onSave(individual)" [disabled]="!individual.valid">SUBMIT</button>

<button (click)="toggle()">Click me to toggle</button>
 </form>
```

TypeScript:

```
 ...
  myCondition=1;
  toggle(){
    this.myCondition = this.myCondition === 2 ?  1 : 2
  }
  ...
```

**animation:**

```
trigger('visibilityChanged', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-40px)' }),
            animate(600, style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }),
            animate(600, style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-40px)' 
       }))
    ])
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oekqp7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Got my anwser, I was applying the animation upon the div wrapping the form which is why animations were not appearing. Thanks for your answer again! :)

Comment: @Vega i am little bit confusing in without state how can animation determine which transition will be executes?

Comment: :enter is the shortcut for  0->1 and :leave is for 1->0, so the states are known

Comment: but why isn't working if we define state and then maintain transition based on define state with *ngIf

Comment: visibilityChanged is triggered with ngIf condition. When that condition is false, the element is removed from the dom and :leave is validated. Reversely, if ngif condition is true, element is added to the dom and visibilityChanged is validated to :enter

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mejnds?file=app%2Fapp.component.html please check above link in this i have done with state and transition but not working. why?

Comment: You have a few errors. First don't put condition on @visi... because you already have the condition in ngif. secondly change state to transition with 'enter" and "leave" in .ts need to have ":"-> ":enter". something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhdiwp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts